# Select with link parameters only

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a dropdown with links but I don't want to use the link filename in the url just the parameters.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToNewPage(){
        var url = document.getElementById('list').value;
        if(url != 'none') {
            window.location = url;
        }
    }
</script>

<select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
    <option value='none' selected>Choose an item</option>
    <option value="?one">item1</option>
    <option value="?two">item2</option>
<select>
<input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />


If I use: <option value="index.html?one">item1</option> it will work but:
```

How do I get it to work with it...like this:

```
<option value="?one">item1</option> ?
```

Comment: `index.html` is fixed?

Comment: You could do `window.location = "index.html" + url;`

Comment: Can't it work without it? For example, if you do this on a link: <a href="?one">Click me</a> ...it will work. Can't the same be done on select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`document.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location#Example_.235.3A_Send_a_string_of_data_to_the_server_by_modifying_the_search_property.3A):

```
function goToNewPage() {
    var url = document.getElementById('list').value;
    if(url != 'none') {
        document.location.search = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should. The `.search` adds the `?url=1` part at the end of the URL.

Comment: Is this the whole code you are using? What about your HTML? Are you using an Iframe or something?

Answer (score 1):

If your link filename is "index.html", then you should use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goToNewPage(){
    var url = document.getElementById('list').value;
    if(url != 'none') {
        window.location = "index.html" + url;
    }
}
</script>
```